# Merge Two datasets in R using a common text in the fields

Tags: r, merge

Imagine I have the following dataset.

D1

```
M2_ID   Year    Make    Gear Type   Bodyshape   Fuel Type   Type       Model    Engine Size Doors_Average
784     2015    BMW          M    Cabriolet      Petrol  BMW 3-Series   M320           3        2
```

D2

```
Year    Make    Segment  Model  Bodyshape   Fuel Type   Gear Type   Doors_Average
2008    BMW    4 Medium BMW 320  Cabrio      Diesel         M             2
```

Now I want to compare Cabriolet ( in D1) = Cabrio( in D2) 
Similarly , compare 320 ( in d1.type) = 320 (in D2.Model )

I have tried using

```
 m <- merge(d1,d2 by = c("year", "Make")
```

I cannot understand how to combine ' by.x()' with 'by = c()'. Second: How to compare parts of the text like I explained above.
Edited: 
Added both sets. Explained better. Thank you for pointing out how to edit the question better.

Comment: Did you try the `merge()` function? What exactly is the problem. There are plenty of questions here already about merging data frame. You should provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to show how your case is different.

Comment: add data for D2 as well

Comment: `library("data.table")` # Note: version >= 1.9.7
`setDT(D1)`; 
`setDT(D2)`;
`D2[D1, on = .(Make, Type)]`;

Comment: please add your data using `dput` commands output , so it's reproducible.

Comment: Edited the post. Please check

Comment: `library("data.table")`;  `setDT(D1)`;  `setDT(D2)`;   `D2[D1, on = .(Bodyshape, Model)]`

Comment: install data.table package version 1.9.7 or greater

Comment: make sure, your initial data D1 and D2 are dataframes. To check, use `class(D1)` ;  `class(D2)`

Comment: Sathish I got the following error:  could not find function "."